# Counting features in child table that are related to the report feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, features, count, qgis-expression, many-to-one

I am building out a report template in QGIS. I have a Field Group Section that generates a report page for every feature in Layer A. Layer B is related to Layer A in a many-to-one relationship like so.

**Layer A**

| fid | Primary_Key |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pk_1 |
| 2 | pk_2 |

etc...

**Layer B**

| fid | Foreign_Key | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pk_1 | positive |
| 2 | pk_1 | positive |
| 3 | pk_1 | negative |
| 4 | pk_1 | positive |
| 5 | pk_2 | negative |
| 6 | pk_2 | negative |
| 7 | pk_2 | positive |
| 8 | pk_2 | positive |

etc...

I want to summarize the results field of Layer B on each page of the Layer A Field Group Section of the report. I.e. for, I  want the pk_1 page of the report to include a line that says:

> Layer B Total = 4, Positive = 3, Negative = 1

I can count up the total number of child features using:

```
relation_aggregate('[LayerA]>[LayerB]', 'count', "fid")
```

Is there a way to summarize the Result field by counting up the number of positives and negatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new field with Field calculator on layer A, regardless if there is a relationship defined between LayerA and LayerB or not. Use this expression:

```
with_variable(
    'array',
    with_variable (
        'key',
        "Primary_Key",
        aggregate ('Layer B','array_agg',"Result", filter:="Foreign_Key" = @key)
    ),
    'Layer B total = '  || 
    array_length (@array)  || 
    ', Positive = '  || 
    array_count(@array,'positive')  || 
    ', Negative = '  || 
    array_count(@array,'negative') 
)
```

[image]

---

Explanantion:

- Define a variable called `key` from the `"Primary_Key"` field of the current feature of Layer A. This is to be able to use the value of the attribute inside the `aggregate()` function for the filter condition.
- Define a variable called `array` that is based on the `aggregate()` function using `'array_agg'`: this generates an array of all the values from the field `"Result"` of Layer B where the value of `Foreign_Key` (Layer B) correpsonds to the `"Primary_Key"` field of the current feature of Layer A (= variable `@key`).
- The array created this way (=the variable `@array`) looks like `[ 'Positive' , 'Positive' , 'Positive' , 'negative' ]`. With `array_length ()`, you get the number of elements -> 4. With `array_count(@array,'positive')`, you get the number of elements equal to the value `'positive'`.

Comment: Now comes the hard part... trying to understand why :).

Comment: Here's what I've figured out so far, but I think I'm missing something with the first with_variable function.

Comment: 1. Define a variable called **array** from  .... ?

Comment: 2. Define a variable called **key** from the "Primary_Key" field of the current feature of Layer A.

Comment: 3. Aggregate an array of all values in the "Result" field of 'Layer B' where the "Foreign_Key" field matches the **key** variable defined in Step 2.

Comment: 4. Build a string as: 'Layer B total = ' _the length of the_ **array** _variable_ ', Positive = ' _the number of times 'Positive' shows up in the_ **array** _variable_ ', Negative = ' _the number of times 'Negative' shows up in the_ **array** _variable_

Comment: See edited solution, I added an explanation at the bottom.